# How to fix a Classifier from the Confusion Matrix?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I understand what a confusion matrix is. However, I found very little information on how to fix the classification thereafter.

[image: matrix]

The class 'Manufacturing' is clearly the main source of confusion but how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try different classifiers based on your use-case. I think it may because of fewer samples for class  "manufacturing". If u want to fix classifier than u will have to balance the sample distribution first. If u want to try a new classifier than [classifiers](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning) is available. U can evaluate one by one. Else it depends on the nature of data as well eg. how many features per documents, which features u select, etc. I hope this explanation will help you.